# Problems with logic and creating a table

Tags: java, arrays, logic

I'm trying to create a table using a method and either my logic is wrong or the stack overflow is what is causing my problem, this is what I'm trying to create...
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
And this is what I'm getting

```
1 1 1 1 1  
2 2 2 2 2  
1 2 3 2 1  
2 2 2 2 2  
1 1 1 1 1  
[[I@4d0948bd
```

Here is my code, it's just those 4 corner 2s that need to be ones and if that's fixed my error might be fixed.

```
public class Server{
    public static int[][] tableMaker(){
        int[][] table = new int[5][5];
        for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<table.length; j++){
                if(i==2 && j==2){
                    table[i][j] =3;
                }
                if(i==0 || i==4){
                    table[i][j] = 1;
                }
                if(j==4 || j==0){
                    table[i][j] = 1;
                }
                if((i==1 || i==3) && (j>0 || j<4)){
                    table[i][j] = 2;
                }
                if((i==2 && j==1) || (i==2 && j==3)){
                    table[i][j] = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<table.length; j++){
                System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Here is my print command in the Client

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(Server.tableMaker());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any SO in your o/p...you should probably remove the Stackoverflow tag

Comment: and remove the eclipse tag. What does your question have to do with Eclipse? Might as well tag your OS and computer CPU brand.

Comment: Note that your code will FAIL if your array isn't square. `table.length` is only the `i` axis, yet you're using that value for both the `i` AND `j` axes. You want `j<table[i].length` for the inner loop

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels LOL. Not enough space ;)

Comment: Edit: nonsense tags removed.

Comment: Solved! Hint: Realize the power of `else-if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't call println and pass in the tableMaker() method. That's what is causing you to get the default `toString()` result from a 2D array of int, [[I@4d0948bd. Instead just call the tableMaker method.
2. Re-think your logic of how to create the table by first creating it on paper and thinking through the steps required to create it. I'd use if + else if blocks. i.e., if the cell is on an edge, put in one, else if the cell is one away from an edge (translate logic to Java) put in a 2, else if,...
3. If this were my method, I wouldn't have any println's or print commands in the method at all. I'd create and return the 2D array, and then let the calling code decide what to do with the array -- likely it would use nested for loops, as your method does, but that's up to the calling code.

Comment: Thanks a lot fixed all of my errors, and sorry about the eclipse thing, thought I should of just mentioned it, since I'm writing this in eclipse.....

Comment: @AdamCalcanes: glad you've got it working. No big thing about Eclipse, but understand what it is -- an IDE to help ease your writing code. It's still Java that compiles and runs it. All of your problems are Java language problems, not Eclipse problems (which would include questions about content-assist/auto-complete, Eclipse automatic code formatting, etc....).

Comment: @bluesh43 You obviously understand what I was saying, this is not the grammar forums. Also I don't understand why everyone is so rude. Most people come on here to have other people do their homework, I simply needed help with something that took less then 5 seconds to realize. Which is the problem in most cases. Most problems just require another view for them to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've never had a problem with an eclipse tag until now. Instead of people saying "lol, fail, *downvote* etc." It would be so much easier to explain why not to do something, I'm fairly new to this site if you couldn't tell by my rep.

Answer (score 1):

You may have worked this out already, but you just needed to change the line

```
if((i==1 || i==3) && (j>0 || j<4)){
```

to

```
if((i==1 || i==3) && (j>0 && j<4)){
```